Is $x!$ (factorial) a continuous operation in the topological ring $(\Bbb{Z}, \tau)$ where $\tau =$ Furstenberg's aka the profinite topology?
Let $\Bbb{Z}$ always have the Furstenberg (profinite) topology, $\tau$.  It forms a topological ring which means $+, -, \cdot$ applied finitely are all continuous functions.
Let $f:(\Bbb{N}, \tau \cap \Bbb{N})\to \Bbb{Z}, \ f(x) = x! = x(x-1)(x-2) \cdots (x-(x-1))$ for any $x \in \Bbb{N}$.
We know that $+, -, \cdot,$ etc are all continuous maps $(\Bbb{N}, \tau)^2\to\Bbb{Z}$ when restricted to $\Bbb{N}$.  That is they are continuous with respect to the subspace topology induced on $\Bbb{N}$ the domain.
Define $g : (\Bbb{N}, \tau\cap \Bbb{N})^2\to \Bbb{Z}, \ g(n,x) = x(x-1)\cdots(x-(n-1))$.
Question. Is $g: \Bbb{N}\times\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}$ immediately a continuous function?
Beacause it's only a combination of $+, -, \cdot,$ integer consts and the two variables (in a multivariate polynomial way)
Now we already know from ProofWiki that $h: z \mapsto (z, z),\ \Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{N}\times \Bbb{N}$ is continuous.
This means we may compose:
$$
f(x) = g\circ h(x) \text{ is continuous }.
$$
Supposing the answer to the question is yes.

What is $g(-2,x)$?

@JoséCarlosSantos thank you. I've totally fixed the post.  Now in terms of the subspace $\Bbb{N}$.

Is this result correct?  We can't find anything on this googling around all day

Which result? The one from the title or the one from the body of your post?

@JoséCarlosSantos the title is about the goal.  The question is crucial to the proof.  The goal is what I'm truly after, and that is that factorial is continuous in the $\Bbb{Z}$, profinite topological ring.

I don't even know what “factorial” means  in a topological ring. I thought that you were interested in the continuity of the factorial function from $\Bbb N$ into itself.

@JoséCarlosSantos I've defined what it means....  In a topological ring, you can use $+, -, \cdot,$ etc and all these basic ops are continuous.

You have defined what it means as a function from $\Bbb N$ into $\Bbb N$, not as a function defined in a topological ring.

@JoséCarlosSantos $\Bbb{Z}$ is a topological ring, and $\Bbb{N}$ is a subspace!

@JoséCarlosSantos I don't need it for negative values, ie.

I assume that the question is: is the factorial function from $\Bbb N$ into itself continuous, if we see $\Bbb N$ as a subspace of $\Bbb Z$ endowed with the Furstenberg topology? The answer is negative, since the set of all odd numbers is an open set, but its inverse image with respect to the factorial function is just $\{1\}$, which is not an open set.

Would it matter if I don't mean $\Bbb{N}$ into itself?  I mean $\Bbb{N} \to \Bbb{Z}$.  So that you'd have to take the inverse image $(\cdot)!^{-1}(2\Bbb{Z} + 1)$.

It makes no difference whatsoever.

@Debug If $f$ is a function from $X$ to $Y\subseteq Z$, then its continuous as a function into $Y$ if and only if its continuous as a function into $Z$ (here $Y$ has subspace topology of course). The codomain never matters for continuity.
